# What do these specs mean? I have a Cannondale Road Bike 700x23c

Tags: road-bike, tire, frames, handlebars, cannondale

I've been trying to find the model of my bike but I can't even find the year.

```
700x23c
175
EPE 45% PU 55%
T 430
700
23-622
```

Comment: If you could add a clean and clear photo from the right hand side, using [edit] that would help a lot.   Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 1):

None of that has any bearing on your bike frame - that's mostly in reference to your tyre/rim and components.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 700x23c | Your tyre was a "700C around" and 23 mm wide |
| 175 | Probably a reference to the crank's length in mm |
| EPE 45% PU 55% | Both are kinds of foam, so this is likely the composition in your saddle's cushioning |
| T 430 | this was hard - turns out there's a brand of rim called **Wolber** with a model of T-430 which was sold with some cannondale brand bikes in the mid 80's. More info on those at https://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=c9968930-98e6-4949-8f84-3163adb0a01b&Enum=101 |
| 700 | Restatement of the 700c wheel size |
| 23-622 | This is the modern way of measuring your same tyre, its 622mm across the bead seat (called the Bead Seat Diameter) and has a nominal width of 23mm when installed. |

I'm guessing your bike is a cannondale road bike, something like: 
 [image]